How do you apply the Concatenate function in Power Apps when using the Patch function in claims?
Tried several codes but I can't get it:
Patch(DUTY, Defaults(DUTY),{

 OCC_Claims:{
            Claims: "i:0#.f|membership|" & Lower(cmb_soconduty_login_1.Selected.Email),
            Department: "",
            DisplayName: "",
            Email: "",
            JobTitle: "",
            Picture: "" } })

Situation: Selecting 2 items in cmb_soconduty_login_1.
For ex: person1@gmail.com and person2@gmail.com
Result in SharePoint list: person2gmail.com, person2gmail.com
How can I make it to: persongmail.com, person2gmail.com

What is the data type of OCC_Claims column in SharePoint list, Text or People (Person or Group)? If People, does it allow multiple selections in the list?

Considering, OCC is your column name and column type is "Person or Group" with multiple selections allowed in the SharePoint list AND cmb_soconduty_login_1 is combo box in Power Apps which also allows multiple selection:
Try using code like:
Clear(colOCC);

ForAll(
    cmb_soconduty_login_1.SelectedItems,
    Collect(
        colOCC,
        {
            '@odata.type': "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedUser",
            Department: "",
            Claims: "i:0#.f|membership|" & ThisRecord.Email,
            DisplayName: ThisRecord.DisplayName,
            Email: ThisRecord.Email,
            JobTitle: "",
            Picture: ""
        }
    )
);

Patch(
    DUTY,
    Defaults(DUTY),
    {
        OCC: colOCC
    }
)

You can change the ThisRecord.Email and ThisRecord.DisplayName property names as per the data source you are using for cmb_soconduty_login_1 combo box.
